# How to compare two column of a file and a list and print not matching pattern with awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a data file `A.tsv` (field separator = `\t`) :

```
id  mutation
243 siti,toto,mumu
254     
267 lala,siti,sojo
289 lala
```

and a template file `B.txt` (field separator = not important because only one line and one column) :

```
lala,siti,mumu
```

I want to create a new column in `A.tsv`(but in a new file `C.tsv`) named `mutation_not` were are printed only the mutation present in the `mutation` column of `A.tsv` that are not present in the list of `B.txt`.

`C.tsv` looks like this:

```
id  mutation    mutation_not
243 siti,toto,mumu  toto
254     
267 lala,siti,sojo  sojo
289 lala
```

I tried with exclude:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {exclude[$0];next} !($0 in exclude)' file2 file1
```

but I don't have any good result. Do you have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk ' BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
NR==FNR{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) muts[$i]; next }
FNR>1  { len=split($2, tmp, ",");
         for(i=1; i<=len; i++) buf= buf (tmp[i] in muts?"":(buf==""?"":",") tmp[i])
       }
{ print $0, (FNR==1?"mutation_not":buf); buf="" }' FS=',' fileB FS='\t' fileA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"; }
NR==FNR{ar[$1]=$1;next}
FNR==1{$(NF+1) = "mutation_not"}
FNR>1{split($2,a,","); 
for(i in a) if (a[i] in ar) ; 
else ncol[$1] = (ncol[$1])? ncol[$1] "," a[i] : a[i]; 
$(NF+1) = ncol[$1]}1' 
RS="," B.txt  RS="\n" FS="\t" A.tsv
```

Assuming all fields are separated by comma and have only one line, Record Separator(`RS`) is set to comma for file `B.txt`.

`NR==FNR{ar[$1]=$1;next` creates an array `ar` indexed on first field of first file.

`FNR==1{$(NF+1) = "mutation_not"` creates one more column in header name.

`FNR>1{split($2,a,",")` splits second field of `A.tsv` to an array `a`.

Next entry not present in `B.txt` is saved to `ncol` array.
`$(NF+1) = ncol[$1]` creates one more column with elements of array `ncol`.

Answer (score 0):

We will form a `set` s2 out of the comma-separated elements of the file B.txt

Then for each line of A.tsv we will convert the second field into a set and subtract the s2 set from it. This gets us the mutations present in  A.tsv not found in B.txt. Then we join the resulting elements and print it along with the original line.

```
python3 -c 'import sys
tsv,txt = sys.argv[1:]
fs,rs = "\t","\n"
ofs,dlm = fs,","

with open(txt) as fh, open(tsv) as f:
  s2 = set(*list(map(lambda x:x.rstrip(rs).split(dlm),fh.readlines())))

  for nr,ln in enumerate(f,1):
    l = ln.rstrip(rs)
    if nr == 1: print(l,"mutation_not",sep=ofs)
    else:
      F = l.split(ofs)
      if len(F) < 2: print(l)
      else: print(l,
  dlm.join({*F[1].split(dlm)}-s2),sep=ofs)

' A.tsv B.txt
```

Result:

```
id  mutation    mutation_not
243 siti,toto,mumu  toto
254
267 lala,siti,sojo  sojo
289 lala
```

---

This time we will use the Gnu sed editor to get the results:

```
sed -Ee '
  1{h;d;}
  2s/\tmutation$/&&_not/;t

  s/\t\S+$/&&,/;T;G
  s/\t/\n/2;ta

  :a
  s/\n([^,]+),(.*\n(.*,)?\1(,|$))/\n\2/;ta
  s/\n([^,\n]+),/\t\1\n/;ta

  s/\n.*//
' B.txt A.tsv
```

Idea being that Btxt file is stored in hold (assuming it us one line) and each line of A.tsv is appended by the B.txt contents and the mutations are ticked off that are found in B.txt. After all mutations have been looked at the line is printed.